# Let $f(n)$ be the number of ways to 'completely partition' $S$. Find an expression for $f(n)$ (preferrably with non-recursive arguments)

Tags: combinatorics, recursion

Question taken from Q4 of this handout: [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-a34-mathematical-problem-solving-putnam-seminar-fall-2018/assignments/MIT18_A34F18PS1.pdf).

Let $S$ be a set of $n$ elements. Let $f(n)$ be the number of ways to completely partition $S$. Here, a complete partition is defined as follows:
If S has more than one element, partition $S$ into two disjoint nonempty subsets $S_1$ and $S_2$.
Then take one of the sets $S_1, S_2$ with more than one element, and partition it into two disjoint nonempty subsets $S_3$ and $S_4$, then take one of the sets with more than one element and partition it into two disjoint nonempty subsets, etc., until only one-element subsets remain. We call this a complete partition of $S$. The order in which the sets are split is important.

**Example**. Let $S={1,2,3}$. For simplicity, write $S$ as $123$. Then there are 3 possible partitions.
$$123 \to 1, 23 \to 1, ,2 ,3$$
$$123 \to 2, 13 \to 2, ,1 ,3$$
$$123 \to 3, 12 \to 3, ,1 ,2$$

The order of the partitioning matters. For example, if you have $S = 1234$, then
$$ 1234 \to 12, 34 \to 1,2, 34 \to 1,2,3,4 $$
$$ 1234 \to 12, 34 \to 12, 3,4 \to 1,2,3,4 $$
are two separate ways to completely partition $S$.

The first few values of $f(n)$ are

- $f(1) = 1$
- $f(2) = 1$
- $f(3) = 3$
- $f(4) = 18$

I have thought of a recursive way to compute these values. I imagine things as going in reverse, i.e. $f(n)$ is counting the number of ways to combine $n$ singleton sets into a single set of size $n$. Then to compute $f(n+1)$, there are $n+1 \choose 2$ possible first steps, because you choose any two singleton sets to combine together. Thus, $f(n+1) = {n+1 \choose 2}f(n)$. Solving the reccurence, I get
$$ f(n) = \frac{(n)! (n-1)!}{2^{n-1}} $$
From this, I can compute
$$ f(5) = 180, \quad f(6) = 2700, ...$$

However, the handout actually encourages searching for a nonrecursive solution. Is there a some combinatorial way to get the same answer? Or some way of interpreting this closed form, so that it is more clear why this closed form gives the answer.

Thanks for the help, and if there is any problems with my reasoning please let me know too.

Comment: Isn't your solution a non-recursive solution? You may have used a recursion to get it, but I don't see any recursion in your final formula.

Comment: yes, but I am trying to think of an 'explanation' for this closed form that I found. Or some way of interpreting the closed form, which would make it evident that it is the answer.

Comment: I agree with @QC_QAOA -- your answer is perfectly fine and non-recursive.  Or rather, if you answer is recursive, then so is the factorial $n!$ itself!  After all, how many ways $g(n)$ are there to permute $n$ elements?  Well $g(n) = n g(n-1) = \dots = n!$ so you might as well argue the factorial is recursive.

Comment: I think the handout is trying to NOT accept an answer of the form $f(n) = \frac12 \times \sum_{1 \le k < n} {n \choose k} f(k) f(n-k) {n-2 \choose k-1}$ (I'm not sure I got that right!) i.e. a brute-force, top-down and truly recursive approach.

Comment: If there’s a direct combinatorial way to see why $f(n)$ is what it is, you might think Erdős would have mentioned it in his proof of Theorem 3 here... https://users.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1974-15.pdf

Comment: @antkam I see where you are coming from, and what you said makes sense.

Comment: @SteveKass Thats a great link, and also further convinces me that I should move on from this problem. Thanks for all your inputs!

Comment: @eatfood - yeah the handout should have said "closed form solution" instead of "non-recursive" :)  (assuming factorials are considered closed form).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any complete partition is completely described by the following: arrange the numbers in a line ($n!$ possibilities), order the gaps between the $n$ terms ($(n-1)!$ possibilities).  Then each partition simply cuts at the next gap.

Clearly you have counted each complete partition $2^{n-1}$ times, as for each of the $n-1$ partitions you could have placed the pieces either side of each other.

Comment: That's brilliant - thank you!